# How to store data files permanently and locally only with iOS 5+ and Cordova 3.5?

Tags: ios, cordova, storage, icloud

I would like to store some data files in a quite permanent location, which should *not* be synchronized with iCloud.

Following Cordova documentation, `cordova.file.cacheDirectory` is my best option:

> `cordova.file.cacheDirectory` - Directory for cached data files or any files that your app can re-create easily. The OS may delete these files when the device runs low on storage, nevertheless, apps should not rely on the OS to delete files in here

In order to control if I reach my goal, I check the size of data synchronized by iCloud:

> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps" Check your app's storage

Well, my app is always so heavy...

Here is what I did so far :

- Cloud entitlement is turned off in Xcode
- config.xml

  ```
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
  ```
- Javascript

  ```
  function onDeviceReady(){
      window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem ;
      window.requestFileSYstem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function(){
         console.log('Error FS');         
      });
  }

  function gotFS(fileSystem){
      window.cacheFS = fileSystem.cacheDirectory;
  }

  document.addEventListener('deviceReady', onDeviceReady, false);
  ```

  and then, I use `cacheFS.toURL()` as a base directory to store the files.

Can you see what I missed?

Apple says that data that should not be synchronized should have a "do not backup" attribute, `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute for NSURL objects, `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute for CFURLRef objects. I don't know what those objects are, and how to apply attributes with Cordova...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I discovered a `NoCloud` folder created at the root of the app document directory. All data stored in this folder is not uploaded to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file with something like this:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    cordova.file.dataDirectory,
    function gotDir(dir) {
        console.log("Data directory located");
        dir.getFile("new_file", {create:true},
                    function(file) {
                        console.log("got the file", file);
                        file.createWriter(this.gotFileWriter,
                                          function fail() {
                                              console.log("Unable to create the writer");
                                         });
                   });
        },
        function fail() {
            console.log("Unable to locate the data dir");
    });
```